# Compiler warnings clobber when running make with multiple jobs

Tags: c, jenkins, gnu-make

I'm running a make with multiple jobs (-j4) on Windows.  At the end of the build, I have Jenkins scrape the console log and collect the number and type of compiler warnings.  The problem (I think) is that the multiple make jobs all have the same stdout, so occasionally (less often than you might think) the output of one job gets clobbered by the output of another job.  For example:

```
ctc W549: D:\path\to\filename.c 10000/3 condition is always true
ctc W549: D:\path\to\file^ctc W588: D:\path\to\somefile.c dead assignment eliminated
name.c 10000/3 condition is always true
```

In line 2 above, I inserted a caret where one warning got chopped.  Line 3 is what *should* have been after the caret on line 2.

It seems like the jobs all flush their stdout buffers to the console at different times; is there any way to mitigate this?  The problem is that the warning scraper has trouble with the partially clobbered lines.

One option is to use -j1, but I'd like to continue to take advantage of multiple cores if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the --output-sync option. This feature was added in version 4.0 of GNU Make.

As per the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html):

> `--output-sync[=type]`
>
> Ensure that the complete output from each recipe is printed in one uninterrupted sequence. This option is only useful when using the --jobs option to run multiple recipes simultaneously (see Parallel Execution) Without this option output will be displayed as it is generated by the recipes.

Comment: FYI you need GNU make 4.0 or better for output sync support.

Comment: Thank you immibis.  There it is, right in the docs.  I appreciate being able to ask a question in plain English -- I didn't know what to search for in the docs, and according to @MadScientist I wouldn't have found anything as I need Make 4.0+ and I'm using 3.8 at the moment.  Thanks so much for both of your comments.

Comment: There is no version 3.8.  You mean 3.80?  That's really old: released in 2002!  Just to note, the online docs are always for the latest version so you would have found it there, but the option would not have worked on your older version of GNU make.

Comment: 3.81 is what I'm using, @MadScientist

Comment: 3.81 was released 12 years ago so... only very old :p :)

Comment: I'm aware but -- make is make.  If I'm able to build and pass my tests make 3.81, there is no reason for to update it unless I need a new feature like --output-sync.